# GeoServer add external WMS service

Tags: geoserver, wms, configuration

I use GeoServer war 2.4.5 with Tomcat. When I try to add a WMS data source  from add store, it gives:

`"Connection test failed: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target" and wms Capabilities URL is "https://"`

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you fixed this?

Answer (score 3):

Error means that the remote server does not have a valid certificate from a trusted certificate authority. What you should do is to add this certificate into your local storage of trusted certificates. That storage is inside the jre that you are using for running Geoserver and the tool to use is "keytool". This link seems to have detailed instructions http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=210